# Hide download button in sonata admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I would like to hide "Download" button on Sonata Admin from some of custom entity. How to hide/delete it?

If i override `base_list.html.twig` and remove the download button from table_footer, it disappears all of entity lists. Is there any way to hide it from Admin class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PROBLEM SOLVED!

I solved it by managing user roles. For example:

You want to remove Download button in Post section. So you need to add below code in `app/config/security.yml`

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_PUBLISHER:
            - ROLE_ADMIN_POST_CREATE
            - ROLE_ADMIN_POST_EDIT
            - ROLE_ADMIN_POST_LIST
            - ROLE_ADMIN_POST_VIEW
            - ROLE_ADMIN_POST_EXPORT #If you comment or delete this line. Download button don't show in Sonata Post List.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can hide the "download" button by removing the corresponding route:

```
class YourClass extends AbstractAdmin {

  public function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    $collection->remove('export');
  }
}
```