# How to remove Download button from "configureListFields"?

Tags: symfony4, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

How to remove this Download button from sonata admin List View?

Here is the image of what I want to 
[remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raU4a.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide download button in sonata admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734213/hide-download-button-in-sonata-admin)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there is an authorization called EXPORT that you can or can not attribute to a role